# How to get a 5 by 5 grid in css?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-grid

I have the layout, below.
How can I make a grid layout that has 5 rows and 5 columns, so a 5 by 5 grid?

```css
.box {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're almost there. Use `repeat` create 5 rows and columns.

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 100px);
grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 100px);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.box {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 100px);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
</div>
```